# UDP Client can't receive any data

Tags: c#, .net, server, network-programming

I've started learning System.Net, and coded a simple UDP client-server chat application.

The client and server are both located on my machine (via local) for simplicity reasons.

I can send a message from client to server and write it there, but after that, the **client should receive a hardcoded message too** (Hello again!), which is my problem.

[Screenshot of application (server and client)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mvzg0.png)

**Client code:**

```
public class UDPClient
        {
            private Socket clientSocket;
            private EndPoint epSend, epRecieve;

            private byte[] dataBuffer;
            private ArraySegment<byte> dataBufferSegments;

            /// <summary>
            /// initializing client with buffer, end points of server and client (for sending and listening)
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="address"></param>
            /// <param name="port">for future port-forwarding</param>
            public void Initialize(IPAddress address, int port = 0)
            {
                dataBuffer = new byte[4096];
                dataBufferSegments = new ArraySegment<byte>(dataBuffer);

                epRecieve = new IPEndPoint(address, clientListenOn);
                epSend = new IPEndPoint(address, serverListenOn);

                Console.WriteLine(epRecieve.Serialize());
                Console.WriteLine(epSend.Serialize());

                clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
                clientSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.PacketInformation, true);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// async task for listening on packets
            /// </summary>
            public void Listen()
            {
                _ = Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    SocketReceiveMessageFromResult res;
                    while (true)
                    {
                        res = await clientSocket.ReceiveMessageFromAsync(dataBufferSegments, SocketFlags.None, epRecieve);

                        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataBuffer, 0, bufferSize));
                    }
                });
            }
            /// <summary>
            /// async task for sending data back to server
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="data"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public async Task Send(byte[] data)
            {
                var s = new ArraySegment<byte>(data);
                await clientSocket.SendToAsync(s, SocketFlags.None, epSend);
            }
        }
```

**Server code:**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// UDP Server
    /// </summary>
    public class UDPServer
    {
        private Socket serverSocket;
        private EndPoint epRecieve, epSend;

        private byte[] dataBuffer;
        private ArraySegment<byte> dataBufferSegments;

        public void Initialize()
        {
            dataBuffer = new byte[4096];
            dataBufferSegments = new ArraySegment<byte>(dataBuffer);

            epRecieve = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, serverListenOn);

            Console.WriteLine(epRecieve.Serialize());

            serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            serverSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.PacketInformation, true);
            serverSocket.Bind(epRecieve);
        }

        public void Listen()
        {
            _ = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                SocketReceiveMessageFromResult res;
                while (true)
                {
                    res = await serverSocket.ReceiveMessageFromAsync(dataBufferSegments, SocketFlags.None, epRecieve);
                    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataBuffer, 0, bufferSize));

                    Console.WriteLine(res.RemoteEndPoint);
                    Console.WriteLine(res.ReceivedBytes.ConvertToString());
                    Console.WriteLine(res.PacketInformation.Address);

                    epSend = new IPEndPoint(res.PacketInformation.Address, clientListenOn);

                    Console.WriteLine(epSend.Serialize());

                    //this doesn't seem to work...
                    await SendTo(epSend, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello back!"));
                }
            });
        }

        public async Task SendTo(EndPoint recipient, byte[] data)
        {
            var s = new ArraySegment<byte>(data);
            await serverSocket.SendToAsync(s, SocketFlags.None, recipient);
        }
    }
```

**Server main code:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Network.UDPServer server = new Network.UDPServer();
            server.Initialize();
            server.Listen();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

**Client main code:**

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Network.UDPClient client = new Network.UDPClient();

            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Loopback;
            Console.WriteLine(ip.ToString());

            client.Initialize(ip);
            client.Listen();
            await client.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Console.ReadLine()));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Thus I would like anybody to pinpoint out what's wrong with my system.

Much appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pasted your code on Visual Studio and with minor monifications (some missing fields etc), the problem I came across is the following:

On your UDP client, this line throws an exception of type `InvalidOperationException`.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'You must call the Bind method before performing this operation.'
```

```cs
res = await clientSocket.ReceiveMessageFromAsync(dataBufferSegments, SocketFlags.None, epRecieve);
```

You need to bind the socket to a local endpoint, specifically your receive endpoint. This is done in order to associate that socket with that specific endpoint and receive data from it.

```
            public void Initialize(IPAddress address, int port = 0)
            {
                dataBuffer = new byte[4096];
                dataBufferSegments = new ArraySegment<byte>(dataBuffer);

                epRecieve = new IPEndPoint(address, clientListenOn);
                epSend = new IPEndPoint(address, serverListenOn);

                Console.WriteLine(epRecieve.Serialize());
                Console.WriteLine(epSend.Serialize());

                clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
                clientSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.PacketInformation, true);
                _clientSocket.Bind(_epRecieve);
            }
```

You can read more here:
[MSDN - Socket.Bind(EndPoint) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.bind)

Comment: Well, that works, but it's very strange because that's the first thing I've done (which was logical to me) - and it throwed exception "something something about not being able to bind this socket on local" (maybe I was trying to bind local socket with the same port idk). 
In any case this works now, much appreciate!

Comment: Maybe you tried to bind your socket to a port which already had a socket bound to it? Or you tried to bind after you started listening/connected? Hard to say without the exception data.

Comment: Yes, the more I think about it, the more I believe that's the case. I even stated this in the first comment. Anyway, it works now, which is the most important. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark this as a solution if it helped you solve the issue. Have a good day!